# How to retrieve attributes of requested Action Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, reflection, html-helper

I'm trying to peek at any authentication attributes which may be decorating action methods in my controllers in an MVC 3 application.  I'm doing this in my own HtmlHelper extension methods which are basically wrappers to ActionLink (to give you the context of what information I have available at runtime).  I have a basic solution in place, but overloaded methods have just made it explode.  I know that the framework is internally resolving urls to action methods, but after looking through the code for System.Web.Mvc.LinkExtensions, I still haven't found precisely how that is happening, so I'm a bit stuck as to how to tackle this issue.

Here's the code I have so far for resolving the relevant method:

```
private static bool _IsUserAuthorized(HtmlHelper html,
  string controllerName, string actionName)
{
  controllerName = controllerName ??
    html.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");

  var factory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
  var controller = factory.CreateController(
    html.ViewContext.RequestContext, controllerName);

  Type controllerType = controller.GetType();
  var methodInfo = controllerType.GetMethod(actionName,
    BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

  ... check authentication
}
```

So my current problem is that when a method is overridden, I get "ambiguous match found" exceptions.  I'm guessing I need to process the RouteValues to resolve any parameters to the method so I can unambiguously identify the right one.  Does anyone have some pointers on how to do this?  Alternately, does the framework already provide a means of resolving the exact method needed?

Thanks so much!

Comment: OK, so I've kept digging in the MVC3 source code and it looks like I need to get a ControllerDescriptor instance and use that to get an ActionDescriptor for the appropriate action method.  So if that's the case, how do I get the ControllerContext of the appropriate controller when the requested action method is not the controller in HtmlHelper.ViewContext.Controller?

Comment: Getting a ControllerContext turns out to be pretty straightforward.  Getting a ControllerDescriptor, not so much.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Found code  [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffreyzhao/archive/2009/01/30/extend-asp-net-mvc-for-asynchronous-action.aspx) for getting the ControllerDescriptor and ActionDescriptor.  Getting closer...

Comment: The link above was a red herring.  Can't figure out how to use MethodInvoker and I really would rather not add a dependency on System.Windows.Forms.  ugh.  Back to MVC code

Comment: Well, I have an answer now and I was going to post the code I came up with, but I have to wait another six hours before I can do so.  Short answer: got a controller descriptor with new ReflectedControllerDescriptor, then called FindAction on that object to get the ActionDescriptor I needed.  I'll post the code when I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: Updated the method to include insights from [this page](http://vivien-chevallier.com/Articles/create-an-authorized-action-link-extension-for-aspnet-mvc-3).  This final version peeks the `AuthorizationFilters` for the requested action method and checks whether the user is authorized to perform the action.

So I dug around in `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker` and found the methods and constructors I needed.
`ControllerDescriptor.FindAction()` ended up being the key.  Below, I've copied the method I wrote that will <strike>retrieve all the attributes</strike>:

```
private static bool _IsUserAuthorized(HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
                                      string controllerName,
                                      string actionName)
{
    ControllerContext controllerContext = null;
    
    // if controllerName is null or empty,
    // we'll use the current controller in HtmlHelper.ViewContext.
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName))
    {
        controllerContext = htmlHelper.ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext;
    } else {  // use the controller factory to get the requested controller
        var factory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
        
        var controller = (ControllerBase)factory.CreateController(
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, controllerName);
            
        controllerContext = new ControllerContext(
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, controller);
    }
    
    var controllerType = controllerContext.Controller.GetType();
    var controllerDescriptor = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controllerType);
    var actionDescriptor = controllerDescriptor.FindAction(
        controllerContext, actionName);
    
    if (actionDescriptor == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    var filters = new FilterInfo(
        FilterProviders.Providers.GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor)
    );
    
    var authContext = new AuthorizationContext(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);
    foreach (IAuthorizationFilter authFilter in filters.AuthorizationFilters)
    {
        authFilter.OnAuthorization(authContext);
        if (authContext.Result != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to add authorization code is using an [Authorization Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).

[IAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter.onauthorization%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) provides an [AuthorizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizationcontext%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) object which has an `ActionDescriptor` property.

Comment: We're using Authorization Filters already, but unless I'm missing it, the framework doesn't provide you with a means of inspecting that authorization prior to invoking an action.  I'm trying to hide links from users who don't have access to perform the actions being linked to, so I need to inspect the authorization attributes before rendering html.  Handling OnAuthorization will be too late in the chain for the functionality I need.